# How do I keep track of a user's items?

Tags: c#

I'm making a text based adventure game in the command prompt, and I need to add in a way to keep track of any coins they collect by entering a certain room, and if they pick up the one and only weapon in the maze.

If they have enough coins or the weapon then they can complete the game. If they don't they die.
I have almost finished the game I just don't know the best way to add in a way of tracking the amount of coins they have or if they have been in the weapon room.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GameTitle();
        Start();
    }

    public static void GameTitle()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to The Maze.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to start.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        Start();

    }
    public int coins = 0; // Keeps track of coins
    public bool weapon = false;

    public static void Start()
    {
        string choice;

        Console.WriteLine("You slowly wake up in an old, decrepit abandoned building. You get the immediate sense you're in an insane asylum.");
        Console.WriteLine("You look around and there are three doors directly in front of you in the eerily silent room.");
        Console.WriteLine("A sign on the wall reads:");
        Console.WriteLine("Choose carefully, once a door is opened, it will never open again.");
        Console.WriteLine("Which door do you choose");
        Console.WriteLine("1. The door to the left.");
        Console.WriteLine("2. The door to the right.");
        Console.WriteLine("3. The door in front of you.");
        Console.Write("Choice: ");
        choice = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        Console.Clear();

        switch (choice)
        {
            case "1":
            case "left":
                {

                    A();
                    break;
                }
            case "2":
            case "right":
                {

                    C();
                    break;
                }
            case "3":
            case "front":
                {
                    B();
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you make the two variables **`static`**, then you can use them from all the methods that themselves are also **`static`**. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) for examples and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just if they find a coin:

```
coins++;
```

And if they enter the room:

```
weapon = true;
```

Comment: How do I add 40 coins as they will be picking up 40 at a time.

Comment: coins = coins + 40;

Answer (score 0):

You could just store the coins in the `coins` variable and use the `weapons` Boolean to know whether or not they have been in that room.

Or you could use a JSON file if you like, that would look a bit more professional but also edit-able on the user's end.